# cakephp 2.x limit the number of records(behavior or model callback method)when add new record

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am relativly new in cakephp and i have never been writing behavior.
So i need to limit the number of records of a model,what i know it must be done with beforeSave

Models: Document | DocumentType . Document->DocumentType
I store the maximal number of document in the DocumentType.

Thats why i am bit confused what i need exactly a model behavior or a callback method(beforeSave) by model.
But i dont know how does this will work with the two model.I began the behavior:

```
     class LimiteBehavior extends ModelBehavior
       {
       public function beforeSave(Model $Model,$options=array())
                    {

}
```

i call this by the modell:

```
public $actsAs=array('Limite');
```

Is this right or should i pass here extra infos?

But now i am confused because i dont know how to use different models in the behavior now.

I have to count the number of Document model records:

```
$this->Document->find('count')
```

I have to check the maximal number of DocumentType:

```
$this->DocumentType->find->('first',array('fields'=>array('max_record')))
```

Now i have to compare this in the Behavior.But i don't know more how to do.
Please help.

Update1:
I don't want to let the user more insert new record when the max_record field is equal with the number of current records

Comment: The requirements for your behaviour are not really clear in this question. Please could you clarify what your expected behaviour is?

Comment: i specified the purpose

Comment: With your edit, you are looking at a validation rule.

Comment: Excusme DavidYell but i was triing to make with the validation.
I don't know how to make it because however,i have to limit the Document model it is not for fit any Document model field,only the records count.
But it depends on DocumentType:max_number field.
So therefore i can not apply for a Document field validation:

In my case the $ check would be:

$this->Document->find('count')==$this->DocumentType->find->('first',array('fields'=>array('max_record')))

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a custom validation rule in your model. This validation rule could check the number of items based on your conditions and fail to save based on that rule.

[Read more about custom validation methods in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods).

I would try and make a rule something like this,

```php
<?php
class Document extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'document_type_id' => array(
            'rule' => 'limitDuplicates',
            'message' => __('Maximum number of documents of this type already created')
        )
    );

    public function limitDuplicates($check) {
        $max = $this->DocumentType->field('max_record', ['DocumentType.id' => $check['document_type_id']]);
        $count = $this->DocumentType->find('count', [
            'conditions' => [
                'DocumentType.id' => $check['document_type_id']
            ]
        ]);

        return $count < $max;
    }
}
```